# SET CHAINED Error in Subreport calling stored procedure in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, sybase, jasperserver

I have a subreport which calls a `sybase stored procedure.` The subreport runs fine individually both on ireport and on jasper. When I use the subreport in a main report and run it on *iReport* it runs fine. The trouble lies when I run the same report on *JasperReports*. I get the following error:

`Error Message
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SET CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.`
.

I googled around and didnt find a solution anywhere for my problem. My Subreport is in summary band. I am using *JasperReports Server 4*

Below is the complete error trace.

> Error Message net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement
>   for : statement_transactions Error Trace
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement
>   for : statement_transactions at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:711)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2038)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:118)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:435)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:774)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:732)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:891)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:57)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:320)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.executeReport(ViewReportAction.java:479)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.executeReport(ViewReportAction.java:469)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.runReport(ViewReportAction.java:302)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor536.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:79)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:386)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:560)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:386)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor178.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   at $Proxy17.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.security.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:154)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:184)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:184)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement
>   for : statement_transactions at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:143)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:161)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:684)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:605)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:901)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:609)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
>   ... 1 more Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SET
>   CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction. at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:137)
>   ... 10 more  Error Message net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   Error executing SQL statement for : statement_transactions Error Trace
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement
>   for : statement_transactions at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:143)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:161)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:684)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:605)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:901)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:609)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by:
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SET CHAINED command not allowed
>   within multi-statement transaction. at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:137)
>   ... 10 more  Error Message com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SET
>   CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.  Error
>   Trace com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SET CHAINED command not
>   allowed within multi-statement transaction. at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) at
>   com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:137)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:161)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:684)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:605)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:901)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:609)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error you are seeing is being thrown by the database, as far as I can tell it's not a java error.  You may want to post the Stored Procedure(s) as well.

Comment: The stored procedure runs fine both in iReport and on jasper when we run the subreport separately.The problem lies when I run the sub report from the main report. It executes the main report with the sub report running stored procedure from iReport. The problem lies when I run the report from jasper. I get the above error from jasper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the datasource to JNDI and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Error  ' SET CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction' shows sybase transaction opened while setting chained option. so make sure no transaction openened while using these Set chained mode command.

To check tranasaction use @@trancount - if its greater than 0 then rollback or commit transaction then only use set command